# ToList() retornando somente leitura

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, linq, tipo-anônimo

Segue código:

```
using (var db = new Entities())
{
    var result = db
        .Tabela1
        .Select(x => new
        {
            x.Coluna1,
            x.Coluna2
        })
        .ToList();

    foreach (var item in result)
    {
        if (item.Coluna1 == string.Empty)
        {
            item.Coluna1 = "Novo Valor";
        }
    }

    db.SaveChanges();
}
```

Dentro do `if`, recebo erro:

> A propriedade ou o indexador ".Coluna1" não pode ser atribuído, pois é somente leitura

Segue outro código a seguir (Funciona com a classe "SuaClasse"):

```
using (var db = new Entities())
{
    var result = db
        .Tabela1
        .Select(x => new SuaClasse //Aqui
        {
            x.Coluna1,
            x.Coluna2
        })
        .ToList();

    foreach (var item in result)
    {
        if (item.Coluna1 == string.Empty)
        {
            item.Coluna1 = "Novo Valor";
        }
    }

    db.SaveChanges();
}
```

Claase:

```
public class SuaClasse 
{
    public string Coluna1 { get; set; }
    public string Coluna2 { get; set; }
}
```

Tem como fazer ela funcionar sem criar a classe (exemplo no primeiro código) ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No primeiro exemplo está usando um [tipo anônimo](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/anonymous-types?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397) que tem todos os seus membros imutáveis sempre, portanto não pode mudar o conteúdo, se deseja fazer isto tem que criar uma classe mesmo, como fez no segundo exemplo.

O tipo anônimo existe essencialmente como facilitador para consulta e não é um substituto de um tipo completo para armazenar dados.

Considerando a [pergunta seguinte](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/251121/101) não precisa nem do tipo anônimo, nem de uma nova classe. pegue o tipo da própria entidade e o modifique. Fazendo isto o conteúdo é gerenciado pelo Entity Framework e fará a atualização como deseja. Pode inclusive fazer no próprio LINQ conforme a resposta do Tobias com o devido *plugin*, ainda que o código mostrado em si não atenda a necessidade.

Comment: Não existe outra forma sem ficar criando a classe ? Tipo `Tuple` ?

Comment: Talvez usando uma tupla, mas não acho uma boa ideia neste caso, se vai mexer no objeto crie um tipo específico. Nem tipo anônimo, nem tupla foram criados para isto.

Comment: Então, a melhor forma para modificar valor de um foreach, é criando nova classe ?

Comment: Do jeito que fez no segundo código.

Answer (score 3):

como o Maniero apontou, você não pode manipular um tipo anonimo, porem você pode montar a sua consulta de forma atender a sua condição.

No seu caso em especifico, acredito que seja realizar algo parecido à um:

```
UPDATE Tabela1 
SET Coluna1 = 'Novo Valor' 
WHERE Coluna1 = string.Empty
```

Se estiver utilizando Entoty Framework, você poderá instalar um plugin para realizar este [`Batch Update`](https://github.com/zzzprojects/EntityFramework-Plus/wiki/EF-Batch-Update-%7C-Entity-Framework-Batch-Update-Objects-Without-Loading-Them): [`Z.EntityFramework.Plus.EF6`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Z.EntityFramework.Plus.EF6/)

Então escreva a seguinte consulta:

```
db.Tabela1
    .Where(x => x.Coluna1 == "")
    .Update(x => new Entity() { Coluna1 = "Novo Valor" });
```