# Dúvida - SaveChanges não funciona, apenas retorna 0

Tags: c#

Segue código:

```
using (var db = new Entities())
{
    var result = db.
        Tabela1
        .Where(x => x.Id == 1)
        .Select(x => new SuaClasse
        {
            Coluna1 = x.Coluna1,
        })
        .FirstOrDefault();

    if (result.Coluna1 != string.Empty)
    {
        result.Coluna2 = "Novo valor";
    }               

    var num = db.SaveChanges(); // aqui retorna 0
}
```

Classe:

```
public class SuaClasse 
{
    public string Coluna1 { get; set; }
    public string Coluna2 { get; set; }
}
```

Quero apenas selecionar uma coluna e depois atualizar valor da coluna2, acontece nada, só retorna 0. O que eu fiz de errado ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O `Entity Framework` não alterar [objetos anônimos](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/anonymous-types), e sim só altera aquele que ele tem conhecimento e está contido em seu contexto. Nesse código por exemplo, acontece isso a criação de um tipo que o `Entity` não conhece.

Se precisa alterar campos individualmente, pode escrever o `update` e mandar o `Entity Framework` executar.

***Exemplo:***

```
using (var context = new BloggingContext()) 
{ 
    context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand( 
        "UPDATE dbo.Blogs SET Name = 'Another Name' WHERE BlogId = 1"); 
}
```

também pode trazer informações, exemplo:

```
using (var context = new BloggingContext()) 
{ 
    var blogs = context.Blogs.SqlQuery("SELECT * FROM dbo.Blogs").ToList(); 
}
```

e a maneira que o `Entity Framework` faz é materializar todo o objeto (*como já explicado, contido no seu contexto*) e depois pode fazer alterações no campo e mandar salvar, no seu código algo assim:

```
using (var db = new Entities())
{
    var result = db.Tabela1.Where(x => x.Id == 1).FirstOrDefault();
    if (result != null)
    {
        result.Coluna2 = "Novo valor";
        var num = db.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

<sup>***Referencia:***</sup>

- [Entity Framework Raw SQL Queries](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj592907%28v=vs.113%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)
- [Executing SQL Query in Entity Framework](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/execute-sql-query-in-entity-framework)
- [Anonymous Types (C# Programming Guide)](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/anonymous-types)

Comment: Uma das vantagens de usar o Entity Framework não é evitar de ter de usar SQL?

Comment: @ramaral você perguntou bem, evitar, mas, não quer dizer que não possa usar, e em desenvolvimento de sistemas não temos um regra plena pra tudo, esse maneira por exemplo talvez seja melhor do que materializar objetos e somente alterar um campo... Vai depender da ocasião, mas, não é regra que não possa ser utilizado tanto é que o próprio `framework` promove isso.

Comment: Agora a resposta está quase como eu esperava que fosse: usar SaveChanges()` e, em alternativa, quando se justifique, recorrer ao SQL bruto.

Comment: O duro é o que as pessoas acabam não entendendo @ramaral, só quis demonstrar que existe caminhos que podem ser seguidos, mas, não como regra geral. Talvez ele tenha duvidas de como é isso ou aquilo, acho que o meu contexto é melhor explicado, mas, muitos não veem assim e temos que respeita, obrigado pelo seu comentário.

Comment: Virgilio, não entenda mal os meus comentários. A sua resposta está/estava boa, até porque começava com a explicação do porquê de `SaveChanges()` não funcionar. Eu só acho que, em vez de ter apresentado uma solução com SQL bruto, deveria ter apresentado uma com `SaveChanges()`. A alternativa com SQL é válida e útil em várias situações mas tem de haver uma justificação para usá-la, a pergunta não indiciava alguma.

Comment: @ramaral não entendi mal os comentários, a pergunta não indicava, e não dizia um caminho, estava em aberto, faltou eu colocar a terceira opção, que seria implícita no desenvolvimento com Entity Framework, mas, que aqui deve ser observada.

Comment: É isso, parece então que estamos de acordo:)

Comment: Virgílio, porque a o seu primeiro exemplo de código ou segundo exemplo, não são recomendado a usar (alguns dizem) ? Mais funciona ! Por causa da ORM ?

Comment: @MatheusMiranda é recomendavel usar em momentos que precisa ser utilizados, não existe uma regra para não usar, mas, existe aonde é necessário usar, um exemplo de usar isso se você tiver que alterar um lote de informações aonde você precise setar um valor padrão para 1000 registros, as duas primeiras opções da resposta tem um desempenho melhor do que a 3 forma. No seu caso em especifico com a pesquisa deve retornar um item, ela é talvez nesse caso a melhor, porque a só altera um item da sua tabela, então dizer "Não é recomendavel" está errado, ele pode ser usado ou não depende dos casos ...

Comment: @MatheusMiranda não é só funcionar, é utilizar da maneira e momento correto ... entendeu! As 3 opções são funcionais e corretas, cada uma no seu momento. A sua duvida da pergunta é antes por isso dos exemplos.

Comment: Entendo, tenho um campo com arquivo muito grande com tipo varbinary, é um vídeo. Por isso usei `Select()` para evitar o vídeo grande. Nesse caso é recomendável usar no primeiro exemplo do seu código ? Porque com entity framework sem `Select()` traz todos os campos, daí a memória não agradece.

Comment: @MatheusMiranda pode usar as primeira ou a terceira, como você vai alterar um vídeo por vez acredito que essas duas são satisfatória. Para não ter trabalho adicional, faça com a 3 opção, porque se fizer com a primeira você deve criar um SQLParameter e dizer o tipo para gravar. Agora se você entender que a recuperação é muito lenta e só quer alterar, pode usar a primeira. Faça o teste para ver se existe muita diferença no desempenho.

Answer (score 7):

Você não precisa fazer um select em um objeto anonimo ou de uma classe diferente para em seguida executar um update.

Basta executar o select, alterar o campo, e update em seguida.

```
using (var db = new Entities())
{
    var result = db.
        Tabela1
        .Where(x => x.Id == 1).FirstOrDefault();

    if (result.Coluna1 != string.Empty)
    {
        result.Coluna2 = "Novo valor";
    }               

    var num = db.SaveChanges(); // aqui retorna 0
}
```

Comment: @MatheusMiranda esse varbinary é imagem ? arquivo ? pelo que andei lendo, pra contornar esse problema você deveria colocar essa propriedade em outra entidade, mesmo que seja de relação 1:1. Aí é mais questão da sua necessidade... se é mais fácil fazer outra entidade ou utilizar a query. Vlw